# Set a cell value and keep it editable in inline editing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have to change a cell value by code and keep it editable. With this code, I can change the value of the other cell, but the cell 'paidHour' change to a non-editable state.
How to make it editable again?

```
       editoptions: { dataEvents: [{ type: 'keyup', fn: function (e) {
             var rowId = $(e.target).closest("tr.jqgrow").attr("id");
             var total = parseInt(e.target.value, 10);
             var paidWeek = parseInt($("#List").getCell(rowId, 'paidWeek'), 10);
             var addHourBank = 0;

             if (total >= paidWeek) {
                  addHourBank += (total - paidWeek);
                  total = paidWeek;
             }

             $("#List").setCell(rowId, 'paidHour', total);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure that I understand you correct. It's important to distinguish *editing* and *editable* cells/rows. The editable is the row or the cell which can be edited with respect of form editing, inline editing or cell editing. Probably the cell *are* editing currently and you want to change the value of the cell. In the case you can't use `setCell` method. Instead of that you have to get the `<td>` as DOM or as jQuery wrapper and then set value of the child `<input>` element of the cell.

For example you can use getColumnIndexByName function defined as following

```
var getColumnIndexByName = function (grid, columnName) {
    var cm = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colModel'), l = cm.length, i;
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        if (cm[i].name === columnName) {
            return i; // return the index
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

It gets you the index of the column inside of the row. So you can split the line

```
var rowId = $(e.target).closest("tr.jqgrow").attr("id");
```

into

```
var $tr = $(e.target).closest("tr.jqgrow"), rowId = $tr.attr("id");
```

The `$tr` represents the jQuery wrapper of the DOM of `<tr>`. So to get the `<td>` cell for `'paidHour'` you can use

```
var iCol = getColumnIndexByName ($(this), 'paidHour');
var $td = $tr.find(">td:nth-child(" + (iCol + 1) + ")");
```

and to change the value of the cell you can use

```
$td.find("input").val(total);
```